# Printer pdf in Elementaruy 6

Tags: printer

I have tried to install the cups-pdf package to have PDF printer but I can't do it, is there any other way to have PDF printer in Elementary 6? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If it is a picture, I open it in GIMP and export as .pdf

If it is text document I open it in LibreOffice Writer and export it as .pdf

etc...